# Second argument of WHERE clause not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm baffled, I can't seem to understand why this simple thing it's not working.

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT((birthday),'%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m'))
```

So this brings me the ids of users whose birthday is in the current month. Now, if I add "AND active = 1"
After the date_format clause, it stops working, brings me zero rows, and there are indeed users who meet the requirements, so, what's wrong with:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT((birthday),'%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m')) AND active = 1
```

Comment: Try adding the active column to the select part of the first query and running it to look for some rows where active is true. It could be that it's a type problem and active is maybe not just 0 or 1?

Comment: What is the datatype of `birthday` column ? Also, show us the sample data showcasing the issues

Comment: Try subquery and see if it helps: `select k.id from (select id, active from users where DATE_FORMAT((birthday),'%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m'))k where k.active = 1;`

Comment: "birthday" is a DATE type (yyyy-mm-dd) and "active" is an INT.

Comment: @NikkoClavaguera please create a SQL Fiddle / DB Fiddle showing your claim. There is definitely something wrong with the data.

Comment: It seems like your data may not be what you think it is. The following query might help you determine the state of your data: `select active, (DATE_FORMAT((birthday),'%m')) birthMonth, count(*)
from users
group by active, birthMonth;` This will produce a summary of all values of 'active' found for each birth month found in the users table, along with a count.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DATE_FORMAT` is inefficient because it converts the values to the string first. Use `MONTH()` instead. I also suspect some behavior of `DATE_FORMAT` is the reason your query fails.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    users
WHERE
    active = 1
    AND
    birthday IS NOT NULL
    AND
    MONTH( NOW() ) = MONTH( birthday )
```

Comment: Can you prove this?